# How to create a mask

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

My issue is as follows, I am trying to properly create the function of setValue(unsigned int & var, int k, unsigned int i, int val)

The var is the pass by reference value, int k is the partition, i is our index of the partition, and val is the value we pass into reference. Now, my issue is how to create a mask.

Here is an example, I will use 8 bits instead of the full 32 bits of an unsigned int.

Assume var has the following value: 
(1011) (1001) Our k = 2. 
Now, say we wish to pass the value 5 into index 1. So we need to make var be:
(1011) (0101). Thus in order to get there we need to make the following logic combinations.

var & mask, where mask equals to (1111) (0000)
var = (1011) (0000)
Then we do, var = val | val

(1011) (000) 
(0000) (0101) |

---

(1011) (0101) My question is how do I create the mask function? Here is the code snippet of where i am trying to create it (by the way, i have set my var to be 0 at start before we enter the function):

```
bitSize = sizeof(unsigned int)*8;

    partionSize = (bitSize/k);
    shiftCount = partionSize*i;   

    mask = ~((1<< partionSize)-1) << shiftCount;
    var = var & mask;
    val = val << shiftCount;
    var = var | val;
```

The results, if I say my k =2, and I enter the following 2 values of 5 and 3 are:

5:

shiftc count so far is: 0
Value of mask is: 4294901760
Inside of the function, var so far is 5.

3:

Shift count so far is: 16
value of mask is: 0
Value of var is 196608. Now, 196608 in binary is 110000000000000000, so clearly it only shifted 3 16 times, and did not properly even bother with saving the 5 there. Other wise it should be 110000000000000101. Thank you for any assistance.

**EDIT**

I have edited the mask part to look like this now:

```
if( i == 0)
{
    mask = ~((1<< partionSize)-1);
}
else
{
    mask = ~(((1<< partionSize)-1) << shiftCount);
}
```

This seems to have worked right now. Because now, if I type in 567, and 346 when my k = 2 (I use two to make my life easier for testing if anyone is wondering why it is always 2).

The final value of var is 22676023, which in binary is: 01010110100000001000110111
567 is: 01000110111
and 346 is: 0101011010

Both of these values seem to be present inside of our variable now. Question to the more proficient C++ programmers, does this seem like valid logic on my part?

Comment: What is "the var function"?

Comment: The var function is our 32 bit representation. In essence, it is the variable within which we place our values.

Comment: have you looked at `std::bitset` ?

Comment: I have not, I was not aware of this function and I am not sure if my professor would approve of it. What does it do?

Comment: I still don't understand what's `k` doing.

Comment: K is what splits the variable into partitions. So we are using an unsigned bit, 32 bits. If k is 2, then we have one partition of 16 bits, and another of 16 bits. Think of it as though it creates how many indexes we have, and the relative size of those indexes.

Comment: You have a `var` variable, and a `var` function, it's confusing. Use descriptive names, there is no shortage of letters. You don't need to pass a separate value to a reference. Do you simply need a general example of bitmask?

Comment: I made a few edits, did have a few typos. The main issue was how to properly create a mask value, which I can use on my variable to zero out the bits at the partition that I was interested in passing a new value into.

Answer (score 1):

This is example of bitmask: lets say we have letters 'A' to 'D'

```
A = 1 //on
B = 0 //off
C = 1
D = 1
```

We want a mask that looks like `1011`

We start with `mask = 1` and OR it with 1.

For letter a: `mask = mask | 1` or simply `mask |= 1`

For letter b: we do nothing because it's not set, and so on

```
mask = 1;
a => mask |= 1      //( mask |= (1<<0) )
//b => mask |= 2;   //( mask |= (1<<1) )
c => mask |= 4;     //( mask |= (1<<2) )
d => mask |= 8;     //( mask |= (1<<3) )
```

mask result is `1101`. Note, earlier I said we want `1011`, it's the same thing except the bits are reversed.

```
void SetValue(unsigned int &mask, int index, int turn_on)
{
    if (turn_on)
        mask |= (1 << index);
}

int GetValue(unsigned int mask, int index)
{
    return (mask >> index) & 1;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int mask = 1;

    SetValue(mask, 0, 1);//A
    SetValue(mask, 1, 0);//B
    SetValue(mask, 2, 1);//C
    SetValue(mask, 3, 1);//D
    //up to SetValue(mask, 31, 1);

    //mask is now equal to 13, or 1101
    std::cout << mask << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        std::cout << GetValue(mask, i);

    //This prints 1011 (reverse of 1101). 
    //Again this has to do with the way we
    //are printing the bits. 

    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are asking. Let me know if this answer doesn't relate to your question and I'll delete it.

Comment: I have successfully figured it out, but I would appreciate it if you were to keep the code. Could come in handy, and I would like to see if I can understand as well. Quick question, isn't XOR ^, | is regular OR

Comment: I don't know why I said `XOR`, I meant `OR`, I changed the post